# modulus of continuity of log of absolute value of sine

Tags: real-analysis

What is a tight upper bound for the modulus of continuity of 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\log|\sin\pi x|
\end{equation*}
where the modulus of continuity $M$ is given by

\begin{equation*}
M(h)=\underset{x,y\in[0,1]\\|x-y|\le h}{sup}|f(x)-f(y)|\quad\text{for}\quad0\le h\le1.
\end{equation*}
(Definition based on page 145 of Uniform Distribution of Sequences L. kuipers and H. Niederreiter)

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ tends to $-\infty$ on the endpoints, so $M(h)=\infty$.

Comment: I was interested in bounding the absolute value of a product of the form below for all $t$\\ \begin{equation*} p(t)=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin\pi(t-t_k)}{\sin\pi(t_0-t_k)}\end{equation*}\\Here $0\le t_k\le 1$.  Following suggestions from other people I thought I should take the log and write this in the form\\ \begin{equation*}\sum_{k=1}^n \log|\sin\pi(t-t_k)|\end{equation*} and apply the following result from L. kuipers and H. Niederreiter page 146. \\\begin{equation*}|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^Nf(x_k)-\int_0^1f(x)dx|\le M(D_N^*)\end{equation*}\\Hence, my interest in M above.